# Change orientation change my fragment in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation, drawerlayout

I have three `fragments` in my `DrawerLayolut`:

- Fragment A
- Fragment B
- Fragment C

  By default (in the init of the app) I load the `FragmentA` : and, if I go to the, for instance, `FragmentB` works well.

**Problem:** when I rotate my screen in the `FragmentB`, I come back to the `FragmentA`.

I don't know how to avoid this. I tried with the next code in the `onCreate` of the `AppCompatActivity`:

```
Fragment mFragment = null;

if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myframe) == null) {

   mFragment = new CalendarioFragment();
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.myframe, mFragment ).commit();

} else {

   if(mFragment instanceof FragmentA){
       mFragment = (FragmentA) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myframe);

   }else if(mFragment instanceof FragmentB){
       mFragment = (FragmentB) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myframe);

   }else if(mFragment instanceof FragmentC){
       mFragment = (FragmentC) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myframe);

   }
}
```

But doesn't work as I expected... Could, please, somebody help me with my problem? Please, any help is welcome

I read about this other solution:

```
<activity android:name="CalActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
```

But I think this isn't recomendable... (and doesn't work for me)

Comment: Please any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with `<activity android:name="CalActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"/>` you need to call `onConfigurationChanged()` in your `Activity`. It should look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
    // Your code here to replace fragments correctly
}
```

This is the Android API guide on the subject: [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Though, as you said this is not recommended, a better solution would be using `onSavedInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`, like so:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("currentFragment", 2);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    int fragmentNum = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentFragment");
    // Restore fragment based on fragmentNum
}
```

See this question for more: [Saving Activity State on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-on-android)

Comment: I don't understand "Your code here to replace fragments" Why I need to replace my Fragments? +1 :)

Comment: @MartaGom Because the fragments should be reset to their original state. You will need to use your code to remember which fragment is currently active, and switch back to it in `onConfigurationChanged()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Comment: Now I cant test your answer. I try it tomorrow and if it works I will mark it as a correct answer :) dont worries